# Monitoring variable accesses in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, clang, code-coverage

I'm working on a coverage criterion for multithreaded code and as part of it would like to record accesses to variables. For example, in the code below I'd like to record that variable `x` was written to and `y, z, a[i],` and i were read from.

```
x = y * (int)z + a[i]
```

I've been looking at doing this using Clang's RecursiveASTVisitor and modifying the source to include recording functionality. However, I'm unsure whether this is a sensible approach as my understanding of how Clang works is very incomplete.

Currently, when I find a statement I check whether it is a `BinaryOperator, UnaryOperator, Cast, or DeclRefExpr`. (I'll expand what its capable of once I have the basics working.) If it's a `BinaryOperator, UnaryOperator, or Cast` I check the expression's subexpressions. If it's a DeclRefExpr I can check whether the expression is an lvalue or rvalue (again, simplifying for now), but once I've found DeclRefExpr they are always lvalues. In order to determine whether they were used as `lvalues or rvalues` I have to check its parent, if it was an lvaluetorvalue cast it was used as an rvalue.

I very much feel like I'm taking the wrong approach to this problem as I can only see it getting much more complicated as I have to consider more complex code.

Would there be a better way to approach this?

Thank you

**Edit**

I don't intend to record this information statically. I intend to find uses of variables and insert code that will record accesses to these variables when the code is run.

For example, given the code above (`x = y * (int)z + a[i];`), I would want to produce something like

```
x = y * (int)z + a[i];
recordAccess(<file>, <line>, "x",    &x,    WRITE);
recordAccess(<file>, <line>, "y",    &y,    READ);
recordAccess(<file>, <line>, "z",    &z,    READ);
recordAccess(<file>, <line>, "a[i]", &a[i], READ);
recordAccess(<file>, <line>, "i",    &i,    READ);
```

Comment: What do you want to produce for:  *p=0; ?  How do you expect to figure out the variable name being modified?

Comment: recordAccess(<file>, <line>, "*p", p, WRITE) I suppose.

Comment: That doesn't do what you claim you want to do.  First, it is an *access* to the variable *p*.   Secondly, it does not list the variable (or allocated heap block) to which p points.   How will you get coverage of variables be correct?  Pointers are pretty common in both C and C++.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean. I'd record that p is being read and that *p is being written and from other accesses to the address pointed to by p I'd know which other variables access that memory. Would you provide an example of what you're describing please?

Answer (score 1):

As others have indicated, aliasing makes this impossible. Static analysis of code to answer the questions you are interested is not possible. If it was somehow possible to take a source code file and determine the output just by analyzing the syntax, compilers would produce the output of the resulting program, instead of a compiled program. In short, you are trying to answer the [halting problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem).

Dynamic analysis is what you actually need to answer the questions you are most likely interested in. There is a big market in dynamic analysis of multi-threaded software already.

Comment: Implementing a dynamic analysis for this is hard (not impossible, but hard), too.  In essence you have to replace every pointer access in every compilation unit with a data-access collection mechanism, that can capture somehow the source-code location of the referenced entity.  (We do this with our CheckPointer tool [alas, limited at present to C).

Comment: I agree! What I am trying to point out to the OP, is that while he or she has developed a rational and well thought out problem state arriving at the solution is not nearly as simple. It's perfectly logical to want to analyze multithreaded access to regions of memory. However, it is not as simple as it sounds. Last time I looked, Portland Group had developed products for this sort of thing. I've never had the pleasure of working with them however.

Answer (score 0):

THe main issue here is that you are not considering aliasing. You will only be able to record simple, direct accesses.

But in that case, a simple expression AST visitor is the main way to go. But Clang's RecursiveASTVisitor should, from memory, be able to cut the crap for you and allow you to visit the final variable nodes directly. After all, it should visit every AST node.

Comment: Your first comment is certainly an issue that I need to solve, but I'm starting with something more basic. Whilst every AST node is visited, I'm still uncertain about how to determine how it is being used. For example, is it enough to simply check whether its parent node is an lvalue-to-rvalue cast?

Comment: @tgt: I don't think so.  Consider a function call foo(x), with x defined as a reference argument.  Is x read, or written?  You can't tell without inspecting the body of foo (and even that may not be enough because foo may (turing-complicatedly) invoke something else.  To add to your complications, the definition of the body of foo may not be in the same compilation unit; how will you inspect it then?